# how to return a specific key from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

please can anyone help me with some code to get specific data from an array here's is my array

```
var array = [
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Carl",
    "age": 35
  }
]
```

just want to return name and its values without returning age

thanks in advance.

Comment: please add what "*fetch specific data*" means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Please add an example of what you’d like to get as a result. Do you want an array of numbers or an array of objects with only that one element or only one specific number or...

Answer (score 5):

Use `Array.map()` with array destructuring method so that you get only the `name` key-value. `Array.map()` will have only one parameter so you do not need to mention `return` there:

```js
var array = [ {"name":"Joe", "age":17},{"name":"Bob", "age":17},{"name":"Carl", "age": 35}];
var res = array.map(({name}) => ({name}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why create a new Array, from an Array?

Comment: @Anuga -- You cannot keep downvoting other's answers just because you think that the result should not be this. Let OP comment what he expects, and then he will accept the answer which meets his requirements.

Comment: I am not. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

> Try using the jQuery.inArray() function. I hope it will help you.

```js
   
    
    function functionname(){
     var names = [ {"name":"Joe", "age":17},{"name":"Bob", "age":17},{"name":"Carl", "age": 35}];
            var name = $('#name').val(); 
            if(jQuery.inArray(name, names)) {  
                alert(name +" Is In Array");  
            } else {  
                alert(name + ' Is NOT In Array...');  
            }  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <button onclick="functionname()" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want the value only, The following example will give you only names in a 1d array

```js
var array = [ {"name":"Joe", "age":17},{"name":"Bob", "age":17},{"name":"Carl", "age": 35}];
var res = array.map(({name}) => (name));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#map` to do that. Destructure the name from the object and return a new object with only the name.

See the working demo below:

```js
var array = [{
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": 17
}, {
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 17
}, {
  "name": "Carl",
  "age": 35
}];

var result = array.map(({name, ...rest}) => ({name}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why create a new Array, from an Array?

Comment: @Anuga -- Are you sure that OP doesn't want this? The statement _just want to return name and its values without returning age_ is confusing. That's why, the answers to return just the values are still there.

Comment: Let's see Quote: ***Just want to return name***

Comment: @Anuga -- But why? The quote follows by _and its values_.

Comment: Thanks Guys for you quick response, it's now working. Much appreciated

Comment: @Jayvk1 -- could you accept the answer which suits your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough to access the name attribute of the object you simply need to reference the item in the array and select the name like so:

```
array[i].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function to get a by property object off that array :

```js
var persons = [
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Carl",
    "age": 35
  }
];

function getElement(personList, property, comparable) {
  var arraySize = personList.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
     if (personList[i][property] == comparable) {
         return personList[i]
     }
  }
  return {"name":null, "age":null};
}

console.log(getElement(persons, "name", "Joe")); // outputs { "name": "John", "age" : 17}
console.log(getElement(persons, "name", "Fake John")); // outputs { "name": null, "age" :null}
```

This way you can retrieve your person object by **any** property he has.

Comment: Map uses less code, usually if you want simplicity you go with functional programming, in terms of efficiency, this way is better ;)

Comment: Why would you not just use the `Array.prototype.find` method for this? `persons.find((person) => person.name === 'Joe')`

Answer (score -1):

All these Array.Map functions *facepalm*

```js
var array = [
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Carl",
    "age": 35
  }
]

array.forEach((entry) => {
  console.log(entry.name) /* Do whatever you want with `entry.name` */
})
```